# List variable is not reading properly

Tags: python

so I have generated a list printed below;

```
['Celeste Ng', 'Angie Thomas', 'Gail Honeyman', 'Paula Hawkins', 'Lisa Wingate', 'John 
Green', 'Dan Brown', 'Neil Gaiman', 'Andy Weir', 'Mark T. Sullivan', 'Author', 
'http://www.thewriteteachers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Image-via-tumblr.com-with- 
steel-toes-980x287.jpg', 'https://www.goodreads.com/book/popular_by_date/2017']
```

In the line after I print this list, I call a function that uses it several times by calling elements of the list. However, whenever I keep getting this error;

```
<p>Data sourced from """+str(ExtraData[12])+"""</p>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've tried lowering the element index to trouble fix but it doesn't appear to work for any value. I have used the function four times before in the script and it's worked every time.

EDIT: Here is the surrounding lines in the function and the calling line;

```
Export(ListData3, ExtraData3, Title, TimeStamp)


"""...<td>10</td>
        <th>"""+str(ListData[9])+"""</th>
        <th>"""+str(ExtraData[9])+"""</th>
           </tr>
        </table>

    <p>Data sourced from """+str(ExtraData[12])+"""</p>

        </div>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

---

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 


"C:\Users\Brendan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Brendan\Desktop\ \Study\Uni Shit\Semester 2 2018\IFB104\Assignment 2\the_best_8.4.py", line 611, in BookExport
    Export(ListData3, ExtraData3, Title, TimeStamp)
  File "C:\Users\Brendan\Desktop\ \Study\Uni Shit\Semester 2 2018\IFB104\Assignment 2\the_best_8.4.py", line 233, in Export
    <p>Data sourced from """+str(ExtraData[12])+"""</p>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help would be appreciated,
thanks in advance!

Comment: when you get those errors, what is the value of `len(ExtraData)`?

Comment: I just added `print(len(ExtraData))` just before calling the function and the outcome is 13.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52826171/edit) the question and show the function and how you are calling the function?

Comment: The function is incredibly long as it's automatically writing HTML code with the certain inputs. I'll add the key bit and the calling.

Comment: if you are calling live HTML, it is possible the HTML is getting updated and changing the contents & length of the list

Comment: I'm generating the HTML from scratch. But wouldn't that not be the case anyway since the printed value is correct (for what I want) just before calling the function?

Comment: That code is pretty hard to read. Yes it is the case, which makes me think the error may not be on the `ExtraData` length, but something else, like `ListData`. Can you copy&paste the exact formatted text of the Traceback Error?

Comment: I counted 13 and the len(ExtraData) outputted 13, also. Even when I change the index value in ExtraData, it doesn't work almost as if python sees it as an empty list when running the function.

Comment: then somewhere in the code not shown you may be altering the list. it's going to be pretty hard to say for sure without a [mcve]

Comment: parts of the code like `"""+str(ExtraData[12])+"""` and `+str(ListData[9])+` don't seem necessary as elements in the lists are already strings, which may have been causing the `"concantonate str (not list) to str"` error. This error suggests there is a list where you seem to expect a string.

Comment: Yes I agree, but yesterday I was having issues and that's the only way it'd work because for some reason they were not read as strings. It appears to work without it now so I'll update it, thanks.

Comment: if you are generating the HTML code that the function is reading, it is static data and really shouldn't be behaving differently today from yesterday. Make sure you are running the same script in the same directory, with the same python version, etc.

Comment: It's all the same from yesterday. I've made sure it's all the same script in the same directory with python 3.7.0

Comment: @b-stewart sorry we couldn't find quick solution for your problem, if you can update the question with more relevant code, ideally create an MCVE that reproduces the problem, or provide more debugging info for us, hopefully we can provide a solution.

Comment: @davedwards, Thank you for trying to solve the issue. I'm not sure as to why Python told me the wrong line when the error occurred. At least it's sorted now

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem wasn't in the line the traceback error told me. It turned out to be 20 lines earlier in the function where the list wasn't the required length. I'm not sure why python told me the wrong line caused the error, but its sorted now.

If anyone else has the same problem as me, run through your code printing the values of all variables as that helped me troubleshoot my issue.

Comment: great to hear you sorted it out. posting the resolution for future users good idea, cheers!